# SOQL SubStr In equivalent

Tags: apex, soql

What is the cleanest way to represent the following SQL in a SOQL query?

```
Where SubStr(MR_CONTRACTS.SPD_REF, 1, 2) In ('AM', 'TR', 'AH', 'AC', 'CT')
```

My SalesForce object name is also MR_Contracts
The SalesForce field name is Contract_spd_ref__c

Tried the following with no success.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM MR_Contracts__c     
WHERE Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE 'AM%' 
AND Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE 'TR%' 
AND Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE 'AH%' 
AND Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE 'AC%' 
AND Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE 'CT%'
```

This returns the expected results. Still a longer query that I would like to shorten:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM MR_Contracts__c 
WHERE (Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE 'AM%' 
OR Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE 'TR%'
OR Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE 'AH%' 
OR Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE 'AC%' 
OR Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE 'CT%')
```

Comment: what do you mean no success? what was the error (if any)? or it simply doesnt retrieve the records you expected.

Comment: By no success, I mean with shortened syntax.  Was trying a shorter string like I do in SQL.

Comment: When I use just one param I get expected results . If I use all as in the SELEC above I get no results.
this is OK - SELECT Name FROM MR_Contracts__c WHERE Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE 'TR%'

Comment: Updated the question using OR conditions. is there a shorter syntax suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `Apex` there is a shorter way:

```
List<String> substrings = new List<String> { 'AM%', 'TR%', 'AH%', 'AC%', 'CT%' };
List<MR_Contracts__c> records = [
    SELECT Name FROM MR_contracts__c WHERE Contract_spd_ref__c LIKE :substrings
];
```

If you were using the `IN` clause, you could inline the collection. Unfortunately, this syntax is not supported in raw SOQL when using `LIKE`.

```
SELECT Name FROM MyObject__c WHERE MyField__c IN ('A', 'B', 'C') // will compile

SELECT Name FROM MyObject__c WHERE MyField__c LIKE ('A', 'B', 'C') // will not compile
```

Comment: Is substring supported with MyField__c.  I'd like to just compare the first two characters to the IN Parms using MyObject__c WHERE MyField__c IN ('A', 'B', 'C')

Comment: That's what the LIKE clause is for, but you have to use OR if you're using pure SOQL.